# When I use JAXB to translate the xml file into JavaObject, there are some special fields such as "cCT, cUF" that cannot be assigned

Tags: java, xml

XML content is as follows

```
 <ide>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <cCT>76124683</cCT>
        <CFOP>6351</CFOP>
        <natOp>PRESTACAO DE SERVICO DE TRANSPORTE PARA EXECUCAO DE SERVICO</natOp>
        <mod>57</mod>
        <serie>1</serie>
        <nCT>1155792</nCT>
        <dhEmi>2022-05-01T00:07:04-03:00</dhEmi>
        <tpImp>1</tpImp>
        <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
        <cDV>7</cDV>
        <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
        <tpCTe>0</tpCTe>
        <procEmi>0</procEmi>
        <verProc>0.1.0</verProc>
        <cMunEnv>3550308</cMunEnv>
        <xMunEnv>SAO PAULO</xMunEnv>
        <UFEnv>SP</UFEnv>
        <modal>01</modal>
        <tpServ>2</tpServ>
        <cMunIni>3505708</cMunIni>
        <xMunIni>BARUERI</xMunIni>
        <UFIni>SP</UFIni>
        <cMunFim>4107652</cMunFim>
        <xMunFim>FAZENDA RIO GRANDE</xMunFim>
        <UFFim>PR</UFFim>
        <retira>1</retira>
        <indIEToma>1</indIEToma>
        <toma3>
            <toma>1</toma>
        </toma3>
    </ide>
```

The converted result is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgpm2.png)

As long as the first letter of a field is lowercase and the second letter uppercase is not assigned.

I try to convert these types of fields to lowercase, and then `add @XmlElement(name = "cUF")` to make the fields available normally, but there are too many such fields...

Does anyone have a simple and fast way to solve this problem?

Comment: So you have `private int cUF; public void setCUF(int value); ... public int getCUF();`?

Comment: Yes, there are already get and set methods in java files. now I want to use 
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.